# Does canopen_chain_node create local node?

Tags: ros, ros-canopen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does the canopen_chain_node create a "local" node on the pc with its own object dictionary or does it just manage the nodes on the bus (ex. motors), as  [it can be used as a stand-alone ROS node](http://wiki.ros.org/canopen_chain_node).

I have struggled with understanding the canopen_chain_node and I am realizing that I might have misunderstood what i actually does. I would like for it to create a canopen node on my ROS-pc with its own object dictionary, which i can set up using eds files and read and write using the services `get_object` and `set_object`.

But does `get_object` and `set_object` just use SDO's to read and write from other nodes on the bus, instead of reading from a local object dictionary?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276009/does-canopen_chain_node-create-local-node?/) by [rhas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32293/rhas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2017-11-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As pointed out in the [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/canopen_chain_node):

> It manages a CANopen bus with one or more nodes, which are configures with CANopen EDS/DCF files. The ROS node runs a control loop with CANopen SYNC interval (or with an alternative update interval if the SYNC protocol is not used).

The "node" in `canopen_chain_node` refers to a ROS node, not CANopen node.

> I would like for it to create a canopen node on my ROS-pc with its own object dictionary

At the moment `ros_canopen` only contains the master implementation.
A ROS node that is a CANopen slave node to a CANopen master is an interesting use case.
Please [open an issue](https://github.com/ros-industrial/ros_canopen/issues/new) to describe this feature.

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2017-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2